Mean of the interval of normal distribution
Given a normally distributed data.
And the population mean $\mu$
I want to find estimate the mean of any arbitrary interval $[a,b]$ using the population mean $\mu$, i know it can be done easily using some integrals, however I want to know if the normal distribution have any special properties related to that.
Perhaps the midpoint of the interval is the mean of the interval?

The midpoint of the interval is the mean of the interval only when the interval is symmetric about $\mu$.

You might check the properties of the truncated normal distribution. Knowing the mean and truncation interval is not sufficient. The variance of the normal distribution is also needed.
